# Using pip when a package dependency isn't installable through pip?

Tags: python, pip

So I've written a small python package.  I'd like to set it up to be installed with pip.  But it depends on another package ([odeintw](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw) to be precise), which as far as I can tell cannot be installed with pip.

My options seem to be

1. Include odeintw within the package I'm sending out.  I would much rather not do that if it can be avoided since I don't want to get into the question of what implications this would have on the license I use and making sure that appropriate credit is given.
2. Set it up to install through pip, but leaving out the requirement for odeintw and simply stating in the readme information that the user also needs to get odeintw.  This isn't ideal either since it's much nicer for the user if things just work.

Is there an alternative way to get odeintw installed by pip?

Comment: The given answers are the correct ones, just adding my two cents - if you depend on this package, you could also propose a pull request that adds building the package and uploading it to PyPI. [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/) is very good suited for that. If the maintainer abandoned it and your PR remains unaccepted, you could fork the project and do the build and upload to PyPI yourself - just mention the original project in the readme. This way, you would make the package accessible via PyPI for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install the package you linked to with `pip` by using:

`sudo pip install git+https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw`

Alternatively you can make a file `requirements.txt` in your package directory with the contents:

`git+https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw`

and then cd to the directory and `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: If this is in the `requirements.txt` file, will `pip install my_package_name` (once it's set up on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)) do this?  I want the setup instructions to be as simple as possible for other users.  (and thanks - I wasn't aware that pip could be used to grab things from github)

Comment: I haven't published a package to pypi before, so I can't say for certain. But I believe that is the reason the `-r` flag in `pip` exists. Otherwise any package you installed from `pip` would also require you to install it's prerequisites as well.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [document](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html#packages-not-on-pypi):

You can add non-pip installable packages as:

```
setup(
    ...
    dependency_links=['http://github.com/user/repo/tarball/master#egg=package-1.0']
    ...
)
```